# Checking if polynomials are chromatic polynomials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Consider the following polynomials.

1. $r^2(r-1)(r-2)$
2. $r(r-1)^2(r-2)$
3. $r(r-1)(r-2)^2$
4. $r(r-1)(r^2-2r+2)$
5. $r(r-1)(r^2-3r+3)$
6. $r(r-1)(r-2)(r-3)$

Check if these polynomials are chromatic polynomials of some simple graph.

> Let $G = (X, U)$ be a simple graph, with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges and let $P_G(r)=a_n r^n +a_{n-1} r^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1 r+a_0$ the respective chromatic polynomial. Then we have that the coefficients in $P_G(r)$ alternate in sign and $m=-a_{n-1}$. In addition, the sum of the coefficients of $P_G(r)$ is zero, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n a_i=0$, if and only if $G$ has at least one edge.

> Developing the notable products we have:
>
> 1. $r^2(r-1)(r-2)=r^4-3r^3+2r^2$
> 2. $r(r-1)^2(r-2)=r^4-4r^3+5r^2-2r$
> 3. $(r-1)(r-2)^2=r^4-5r^3+8r^2-4r$
> 4. $r(r-1)(r^2-2r+2)=r^4-3r^3+4r^2-2r$
> 5. $r(r-1)(r^2-3r+3)=r^4-4r^3+6r^2-3r$
> 6. $r(r-1)(r-2)(r-3)=r^4-6r^3+11r^2-6r$
>
> I verified the properties described above for all polynomials and all polynomials satisfy these properties. But my professor told me that one of these polynomials that not is a chromatic polynomial.

**I'm not sure if I'm in the correct way, can anyone help me?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the degree of a chromatic polynomial $n = |V(G)|$ and the coefficient of $r^{n-1} = -|E(G)|$. With these facts, one can find graphs with 1, 2, 3, and 6 as their chromatic polynomial fairly quickly due to their nice form. For example

1. $K_3$ and a singleton. (The chromatic polynomial is the product of the chromatic polynomial of each component.)
2. $K_3$ with an appended leaf.
3. $K_4$ minus an edge.
4. $P_G(2) = 4$, that is $G$ must be bipartite with $3$ edges and $4$ vertices. Furthermore, it must have $2$ connected components (why?).
5. $P_G(2)= 2$ so $G$ must be bipartite with $4$ edges and $4$ vertices, with one connected component (why?).
6. $K_4$.

The remaining, 4. and 5., require a bit more thinking. I hopefully have given helpful hints.

Comment: Thanks for the trouble! ;-)

Comment: @Ejay You're welcome :)